# How to update DatePicker value in wpf DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datepicker, datagrid

I have a 2 DatePicker columns in wpf DataGrid

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date Begin">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding dtBeg, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" LostFocus="TextBlock_LostFocus" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding dtBeg, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" LostFocus="DatePicker_LostFocus" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date End">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding dtEnd, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding dtEnd, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

After the date in the "Date Begin" cell  was changed i want to change date in  "Date End"

```
private void DatePicker_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)sender;
        if (dp.SelectedDate == null) { return; }
        if (dgDates.SelectedItem == null) { return; }
        DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)dgDates.SelectedItem;
        
        DateTime dtEnd = dp.SelectedDate.Value.AddYears(5).AddDays(-1);// or anything else
        rv["dtEnd"] = dtEnd;
    }
```

But value in "Date End" cell  changes only after double click in this cell. Variant with DataRow=dtDates.Select(...) return the same result. How to make the value in the cell "Date End" change after the end of editing " Date Begin"?

Comment: Does this work? rv["dtEnd"].BeginEdit(); rv["dtEnd"] = dtEnd; rv["dtEnd"].EndEdit();

Comment: DataRowView dosnt have events Begin & End Edit

Comment: With this rv["dtEnd"] you select a cell right? Does the cell have these methods (not events)?

Comment: No, i dont need to select this cell. I want to change this cell programmatically after cell "dtBeg" was changed. But, it changes only after begin edit this cell manually/

Comment: Does the cell have the methods I mentioned?